# How can I access a discord widget inside an iFrame without errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble accessing a widget (the discord widget) from selenium. The code sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. I need it to be consistent.

This is the [website](https://slayersclub.bethesda.net/en)

Here's the iframe source I am concerned about :

```
<iframe id="discordIframe" title="discordIframe" src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=162891400684371968&amp;
theme=dark" width="100%" height="365" 
allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
#document
</iframe>
```

The elements I need to check are in the #document, although I've noticed that sometimes the #document doesn't even load in but even when it does, my program still can't find the required element.

Here's a fully reproducible code sample:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.common.by as by
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r'D:\Software\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)

std_wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
extended_wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
iframe_wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 90)

print("Visiting Discord....")
browser.get(r"https://slayersclub.bethesda.net/en/#")
leaderboard = std_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class = 'module top-contributors']"))
                    )
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", leaderboard)
iframes = extended_wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by.By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class = 'frame frame--padding']"))
                            )
iframes[1].click()
discordframe = iframe_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.By.CLASS_NAME, "discordIframe"))
                                    )
browser.switch_to.frame(discordframe)
extended_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.By.CLASS_NAME, "widgetBtnConnect-2fvtGa"))
                    ).click()
```

It's possible to get an error code in pretty much all the `wait` parts of the code as I've noticed. But more so in the `discordIframe` and `widgetBtnConnect-2fvtGa` part. Even though I can clearly see everything has loaded in, the program still keeps waiting and eventually throws out the error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Access Item in Iframe Write This Code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#discordIframe")))
```

To Switch Again Write This Code

```
browser.switch_to_default_content()
```